# Union type for the similar structure of the interfaces

Tags: typescript, reducers, union-types

How to implement Union type with enabled typeof flag for variables in typescript config

[TS playground is there](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20TYPEA%3A%20number%20%3D%201%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20difinition%20here%20breaks%20line%2019%0D%0Ainterface%20ActionA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20typeof%20TYPEA%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entities%3A%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20TYPEB%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20ActionB%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20typeof%20TYPEB%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20reducer%20%3D%20(action%3A%20ActionA%20%7C%20ActionB)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(action.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20TYPEB)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20action.payload.id%20%2F%2F%20is%20not%20defined%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

The removing of type definition in the first line works fine, but tslint generetes the error for it.
Examples in http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html with (entity) did not help.

```
const TYPE_A: string = 'TYPE_A'; // <- type difinition here breaks line 19
interface Action_A {
    type: typeof TYPE_A;
    payload: {
        entities: [];
    }
}

const TYPE_B = 'TYPE_B';
interface Action_B {
    type: typeof TYPE_B;
    payload: {
        id: number
    }
} 

const shouldBeReducer = (action: Action_A | Action_B) => {
    if (action.type === TYPE_A) {
        return action.payload.entites // <- entities field is not defined
    }
}
```

type definition in the reducer should work correct, but exeption is displayed

Comment: What lint error does it break? `const TYPE_A:  'TYPE_A' = 'TYPE_A';` should work if you are forced to write out all types, but I would re-evaluate that rule...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class instead of interface and `instanceof` type guard.

```
const TYPEA: number = 1; // type difinition here breaks line 19
class ActionA {
    type: typeof TYPEA;
    payload: {
        entities: [];
    }
}

const TYPEB = 2;
class ActionB {
    type: typeof TYPEB;
    payload: {
        id: number
    }
} 

const reducer = (action: ActionA | ActionB) => {
    if (action instanceof ActionB) {
        action.payload.id // OK
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20TYPEA%3A%20number%20%3D%201%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20difinition%20here%20breaks%20line%2019%0D%0Aclass%20ActionA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20typeof%20TYPEA%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entities%3A%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20TYPEB%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0Aclass%20ActionB%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20typeof%20TYPEB%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20reducer%20%3D%20(action%3A%20ActionA%20%7C%20ActionB)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(action%20instanceof%20ActionB)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20action.payload.id%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

However if you want to keep interfaces, you should change your code to this:

```
const TYPEA = 1 as 1; // type difinition here breaks line 19
interface ActionA {
    type: 1;
    payload: {
        entities: [];
    }
}

const TYPEB = 2 as 2;
interface ActionB {
    type: typeof TYPEB;
    payload: {
        id: number
    }
} 

const reducer = (action: ActionA | ActionB) => {
    if (action.type === TYPEB) {
        action.payload.id // OK
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20TYPEA%20%3D%201%20as%201%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20difinition%20here%20breaks%20line%2019%0D%0Ainterface%20ActionA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entities%3A%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20TYPEB%20%3D%202%20as%202%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20ActionB%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20typeof%20TYPEB%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20reducer%20%3D%20(action%3A%20ActionA%20%7C%20ActionB)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(action.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20TYPEB)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20action.payload.id%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

The problem was that `TYPEA` and `TYPEB` was inferred as `number` and not number literals (`1`, `2`).